# Custom WindowChrome [ Wpf Core 3.1; MvvmCross 7.0.0 ]

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvmcross, window-chrome

## How to customize the `WindowChrome` class while using *MvvmCross*?

I've got this:

```xml
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="{x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}" ResizeBorderThickness="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness}" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        FontSize="32"
        Text="SOME UPPER CASE TEXT THAT WILL NEVER BE DISPLAYED" />
</Grid>
```

inside my `MvxWindow` and the `WindowStyle` is set to `none`.
The problem is that `MvxWindow` doesn't seem to display anything. That means I can't create the buttons I need either. I don't know if *MvvmCross* expects every UI element to be part of a `View` or what else is going on. Resizing and even right-clicking the invisible border works just fine. Is there any way to do this without having to rebuild the entire `WindowChrome` functionality inside a `View`?

Comment: Maybe helpful: [WPF Custom Window](https://github.com/SourceSara/WpfCustomWindow)

Comment: Thanks, but I already saw this and my problem was MvvmCross specific. I got confused by not being able to create the chrome ui inside the window. Turns out this isn't a problem at all. I just answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this myself;
while there is little difference in creating a custom `WindowChrome` with *MvvmCross*, I'll keep this question up in the hope that it could help someone else.
Not being able to display UI elements in `MvxWindow` is actually no problem at all. Just create the UI in your `View` and set the `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome` property to `true` for each element you need.
There is basically no difference between doing this within a `Window` or a `View`. You just have to keep an eye on your `CaptionHeight` as your `WindowChrome` and your UI are now in two different scripts.
It could look like this:
**Inside your MvxWindow:**

```xml
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="{x:Static SystemParameters.CaptionHeight}" ResizeBorderThickness="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness}" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

**Inside the view displayed by that window:**

```xml
<Menu Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight}">
    <MenuItem Header="_Exit" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />
</Menu>
```